# Do Tezos support multisignature transaction?

Tags: transactions, tezos-signer

If it does, where's the documentation?
Are there any additional fee for multisig tx?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it has been supported since the launch of tezos however the contract was not publicly advertised in the beginning.

Now @arthurb has published an implementation.

Quoting his announcement on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/bgs33n/multisig/)

> It is supported. You can deploy
>   https://github.com/murbard/smart-contracts/blob/master/multisig/michelson/multisig.tz
>   for instance.* More user friendly CLI support is coming but you can
>   already use this. (*) It's implemented in a straightforward way, and
>   its properties (no replay, need the sigs etc) have been formally
>   verifed, nevertheless please read the license
>   https://github.com/murbard/smart-contracts/blob/master/LICENSE

Answer (score 3):

The Tezos command-line client features a few commands for interacting with the Michelson multisig smart contract.

These commands are listed in the section named "Commands for managing a multisig smart contract" of the client manual (https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/api/cli-commands.html).

More gas is required than for a direct transaction, the precise amount of extra gas depends on the number of signers.